# How to get name of selected option and sent it to other php script?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

This is my jQuery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#countries').change(function(){
      $('#countriesForm').submit();
   });
});
</script>
```

and my php code looks like this

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->createUrl($this->id."/".$this->action->id); ?>" id="countriesForm" method='POST'>
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('countries', $select = array(),
 CHtml::listData($countries, 'code', 'name'));
?>
<form>
<div class='description'></div>
```

Can someone pls help me how to get echo/print name or code of the selected country into the div .description.
And how to send the selected code to other php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be like

```
<div class='description'><?php
if( isset($_POST['countries']) ) {
    echo CHtml::encode($_POST['countries']);
}
?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $controller = Yii::app()->controller->id;
    $action =  Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
?>
```

Using this, you get the controller and action performed.

```
<li <?php 
    if ($controller=="site"&&$action=="index"){
        echo 'class="active"'; } ?> >
    <?php echo CHtml::link('Home',array('site/index')); ?>
</li>
```